# Adding external plug ins to gedit in Windows

Tags: gedit

I am using gedit 3.20.1 with Windows 7. I'm unable to add external plugins to gedit. Specifically, I'm trying to add gedit-latex-3.2.1 plugin, but so far all plug ins I've used have not worked.

1. I add the appropriate files to "C:\Program Files\gedit\share\gedit\plugins"
2. Restart gedit
3. Go to Preferences --> Plugins and the latex (or whatever) plugin is not there.

Is it just that these plug ins don't work with Windows, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

Use "C:\Program Files\gedit\lib\gedit\plugins"